# What packages to install in Atom editor for python

Tags: python, package, atom-editor

I am new to python, and trying to set up my environment to start python builds. I am using Atom as an editor. What all should I do? Through some online tutorials, I got these recommendations, but I still get some errors when I open up a python project

- Installed python
- Installed pip

In Atom, installed the following packages:

- linter
- linter-flake8
- linter-ui-default
- busy-signal
- intentions

**I get this error:**
Flake8 crashed!
linter-flake8:: Flake8 threw an error related to:
Failed to spawn command `flake8`. Make sure `flake8` is installed and on your PATH
Please check Atom's Console for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up Atom as an IDE might not be in your best interests to learn python.

Python is a scripting language. Pip is a package manager. Atom is a code editor. All you need now is the command line to bring all of them together.

Open your terminal and cd (change directory) to the location where your file is saved. Run it using the command "python file_name.py" on the terminal.

If you have imported a package in your script that isn't installed on your machine, simply execute "pip install package_name" on the terminal.

Happy programming!

PRO Tips :: If you learn to use vi or vim you can remove Atom from your list of tools. Also, might be a good idea to learn about virtualenv to keep your system sane.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I solved it in the end by brute force.. Removed all packages, and removed atom. Went to terminal and removed every file referring to atom via rm. And then reinstalled! will stick to atom for now - loved the UI :) Need to get into understanding virtual environments soon :)

Comment: Careful while deleting python packages. Most systems now depend on python packages. Your system might not survive a restart if some packages are missing, hence virtualenv. It's always best to install / uninstall software via package managers. Linux has apt, yum, etc.... use homebrew for macs.

Answer (score 0):

The error already tells you what is wrong.

As per the [documentation for linter-flake8](https://atom.io/packages/linter-flake8): *To use this plugin flake8 will need to be installed on your system*.

With regard to installing software, it is generally helpful to put your operating system in the tags. Installing stuff on ms-windows is different from Linux or other UNIX-like operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

search for **script package** and install it.
You can run the code by using **ctrl+shift+b**

The good thing about script package is you can run any code e.g. filename.c, filename.py etc.